# propositional logic define propositional symbols using sheffer stroke

Tags: logic

I am finding this question difficult to understand:

[image]

If it was explained briefly it would really help.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you’re running into or do you just not understand the question? You’re being asked to come up with expressions involving only $P$, $Q$, and $|$ that have the same truth tables as $P\land Q$, etc.

Comment: I am just having trouble understanding the question, could you explain it with just slightly more detail please?

Comment: By the way, it’s worth noting that this exercise has a practical ramification in electronics. It shows that any Boolean function can be constructed using only NAND gates.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s take the easiest one as an example. We must express $\lnot P$ using some combination of $P$’s and $|$’s. Following the hint, the truth table for $P\;|\;P$ is $$
\begin{array}{c c | c c}
P & P & P\;|\;P & \lnot P \\
\hline
T & T & F & F\\
F & F & T & T
\end{array}
$$
We can immediately see from this that $\lnot P \equiv P\;|\;P$.

Now, you must do something similar for $P\land Q$, $P\lor Q$ and $P\Rightarrow Q$. To get you started, notice from the truth table for $P\;|\;Q$ that it’s equivalent to $\lnot(P\land Q)$.

Comment: still cant seem to understand :s is there any other way of explaining it? sorry

Comment: $P\Rightarrow Q$ can be defined using $\land$, $\lor$ and $\lnot$ as either $\lnot P\lor Q$ or $\lnot(P\land\lnot Q)$. They’re asking you to do the same thing, but using the $|$ operator only, for which you’ve been given the truth table. I've shown you how to do that for $\lnot P$. You still have to do it for $P\land Q$, $P\lor Q$ and $P\Rightarrow Q$. I’m not sure how to expain the question any further, so if you’re still confused, you should talk to your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the sheffer stroke as a **function** $S$ where $S(p,q) = true$ for all boolean $p,q$ except when $p=q=true$. Now the question asks you to use only calls to $S$ to construct all the basic logic gates, meaning that you cannot use any logical operations but only $S$. As *amd* has shown, it is easy to obtain the NOT gate because $S(p,p) = \neg p$ for any boolean $p$. Similarly try to figure out how to get the rest. You may need to use $S$ multiple times.